# add object instance id to log4net log 

Tags: log4net

I am trying to use log4net for distributed logging on a cluster.

My software stack is composed of isolated agents which are spreed around the cluster with unique instance id. I would like to add the instance id of each object who is logging to the log being generated but I want all the inherited classes to use the same value for object instance id where I am following the best practice of adding a static logger to every class of mine and even if a class inherit from a base class, it will have its own logger like below

```
 private static ILog _Log =LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

so I can not use the logger name. Also, I do not want to have to add the object instance id to every log that I make and I would it to be automatically done with logn4net log.

I can use the logger context and but the instance id is not global and does not belong to an espcific thread. How should I go about this?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the instance ID to be added to each log message?  If you don't want it there, where would you want it?  If you do want it there, do you think you would be able to get that value every place you are attempting to write a log entry?

Comment: I do want the object id in the log and I am able to get it where I need to log it but the problem is logs at different inheritances level. If I have a class C which is C:B:A and A and B have their own logger based on their type, how do I make an instance of class C log things with its own object id where I would only set that object id once for that object and every log at C B or A level would use that object id?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Nested Diagnostic Contexts to you business classes which provide context information on what is going on. You log messages will be enriched with the NDC information, for example you can add the current id to NDC context and when you log, the log message will be enriched.

```
using(NDC.Push("my context message, and my id is:"+object.id))
{
    ... all log calls will have 'my context message, and my id is:...' included ...
}
```